# How to stop replacing chars with a replacement character �?

Tags: c, unicode

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game with some additional features.

Sometimes when I try to print the array of chars (which is the board) it replaces some of the characters with a black diamond with a white question mark(�) or an empty square box.

What do I need to do to solve this?

```
void print_board(char board[N][N], int n)
{
    printf("\nCurrent board:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("|");

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%c|", board[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I expect a normal board with x's and o's but some of these get replaced by � or an empty box.

```
void change_board(char board[N][N], int moves_history[TWO][N], int row, int column, int player_index, int turns_num, int board_size)
{
    char player_sign = (player_index == FIRST_PLAYER) ? FIRST_PLAYER_SIGN : SECOND_PLAYER_SIGN;
    board[row][column] = player_sign;
    moves_history[0][turns_num-1] = row;
    moves_history[1][turns_num-1] = column;
    print_board(board, board_size);

    if (did_anyone_win(board,player_index, player_sign,board_size,row,column))
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    player_index = (player_index == FIRST_PLAYER) ? SECOND_PLAYER : FIRST_PLAYER;
    player_turn(board,board_size,turns_num,player_index,moves_history);
}

void Undo(char board[N][N], int moves_history[TWO][N], int undo, int board_size, int turns_num, int player_index)
{
    for (int i = turns_num-TWO; i >= turns_num+undo-1; i--)
    {
        board[moves_history[0][i]][moves_history[1][i]] = EMPTY_CELL;
        moves_history[0][i] = 0;
        moves_history[1][i] = 0;
    }

    print_board(board,board_size);

    player_index = player_index == FIRST_PLAYER ? SECOND_PLAYER : FIRST_PLAYER;
    player_turn(board,board_size,turns_num+undo-1,player_index,moves_history);
}
```

These are the only places where I change the board, I don't think there's any bug here but I put them just for reference.

Comment: It depends on what characters you have in the board array? If they're unicode or non character values then they won't be printed correctly. It's not that the characters are being replaced, they're just not being printed how you want them to be since there might be unintended data.

Comment: C uses ASCII not unicode. The reason for the weird output is that some of your characters are unprintable characters, not 'x' or 'o's. Printing them as integers might help you figure out what those characters are. Why they are what they are depends on wherever you setup the array

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. The code you posted works fine if `board` only contains x's and o's.

Comment: The trouble is the interaction between what your program sends to be displayed and the device (terminal window) that display them.  What character codes are you using for `O` and `X`?  What is actually stored in your `board` array?  Why do you define `char board[N][N]` and then `int n` as the array bound?  You would normally use `void print_board(int n, char board[n][n])` using VLA (variable length array) notation.  As it stands, `N` must be a constant of some sort, making the variable `n` probably pointless.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I've seen the described symptom before (only *some* characters are wrong), that's a timing bug in KDE Konsole. If you use that terminal emulator, upgrading to version 19 helps.

Comment: @Nina just to clarify, the user is capable of giving either x or o as an input. printing the array works just fine, but after a couple of turns the x's and th o's in the board we printed earlier turn to � when we print the board again with the new input, not all of them but some of them which is weird.

Comment: @Gufran can you somehow verify al the data in the board is as expected before printing?

Comment: Your program does not replace anything with anything else. It prints garbage characters due to a bug in a portion that you did not show. If you want to ask how to fix your program, you should ask just that question, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the value of EMPTY_CELL?

Comment: @BrandenHuggins  it's '_'

Answer (score 1):

I noticed based on your variable names that you have an NxN matrix for your board. But your move history is an array of size N. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I didn't notice that one, but yeah it seems to be the issue. thank you so much